# What is this Pokémon fanfic? Red trying to beat Blue to becoming champion, and the story is structured as interrogation after capture by Team Rocket

Tags: story-identification, fan-fiction, pokemon

I’m looking for a specific Pokémon fanfiction I read years ago. It was about Red trying to beat his friend/rival Blue to becoming  champion, but Blue has tons of resources as Prof Oaks grandson and Red starts off totally broke.

Prof Oaks helps him out by giving him a beta version of a Pokédex and gives him the job of testing it on his adventures.

He has a special bond with his pikachu and goes around trying to defeat each gym, thwarting Team Rocket along the way.

The story is narrated from Red’s point of view as he is explaining his past during an interrogation while he’s captured by Team Rocket. In one of the chapters, he has to find a ninetails before sunrise or something, but it turns out the ninetails was the matriarch of the family that hired him and keeping each daughter captive through some loophole about never leaving the grounds but eventually the grounds included the family mansion.

Answer (score 3):

Nevermind I just found it! Game of champions by L Lamora, looks like it got taken down in 2018 but someone posted a copy again

Comment: You will be able to accept your answer in 46 hours by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].